# LINQ TO SQL, ADO.NET Entity Framework, T-SQL

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq-to-sql, t-sql, linq-to-entities

Greetings,

I have a few applications/websites running with LINQ to SQL and the other day I decided to go ahead and optimize some of the queries, etc and I found that the size for variable length data types is derived from the parameter value instead of the column actual size?

for example a column is defined as nvarchar(30). when I use linq to query that column with a value that's 5 characters long the parameter in sp_executesql will be defined as nvarchar(5)...this causes a major procedure cache bloat even for a small utility site that has a lot of queries

is there a way to optimize this?

BR,

Comment: What does this have to do with entity framework?

Comment: just wondering if the same issues occur if you use linq to entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF 1, it's the same as the L2S behavior you're seeing. [In EF 4, a default length of 4000 is used](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/upgrading-ef-projects-to-ef4-don-t-forget-to-target-net-4-0/), so the query won't bloat the cache for different param values.